# Before insert trigger on 5.7.9 but not on 5.6.33

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `openings` (
  `code` varchar(9) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `validFrom` date NOT NULL,
  `validTo` date NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and the following `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to set a default value on a `DATE` column:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `openings_default_validFrom` BEFORE INSERT ON `openings` FOR EACH ROW
IF ( ISNULL(new.validFrom) ) THEN
 SET new.validFrom=CURDATE();
END IF;
```

Finally, a procedure to populate the table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_populate_openings (IN prefix CHAR(4), IN num INT)
BEGIN
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  WHILE i < num DO
    INSERT INTO openings (code,validTo) VALUES (prefix, '2017-06-31');
    SET i = i + 1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

All of this works fine when I run the procedure in my local (Windows) installation of MySQL, version 5.7.9-log, but when I try to run it in a server (Linux), version 5.6.33, the trigger doesn't seem to be working, because I get the following error when calling the procedure from liquibase:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'validFrom' doesn't have a default value
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2547)
```

I can manually insert a row without getting any error, but the value set is 0000-00-00.

Any idea of why is it failing or how to fix it? I would prefer to try other options before upgrading the server version.

Comment: Check [BEFORE triggers and NOT NULL columns in MySQL](http://mysqlserverteam.com/before-triggers-and-not-null-columns-in-mysql/).

Comment: @wchiquito Why don't you add it as an answer?

Comment: One option is to add a default value to `\`validFrom\`` column and validate it in the trigger, see example [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xtGjr7ywmViANRzpCizvCJ/0).

Comment: @fancyPants A link to an article I consider better in a comment than in answer.

Comment: @wchiquito Well, you could quote the most important parts.